sync cmp and pwm with xbar IMXRT1024 for zero cross BEMF detection
recently i work on BLDC driver work with imx rt1024 i got so much problem to use internal comparator to detect the zero crossing recently find that the pwm chupping will make the the comparator noisy and no i wonder is there any way to sync pwm signal with acmp to captured only when the pwm signal is in high position ?
